# Formatting a String of a double with swift

Tags: ios, swift

How can i format string of a double with swift?
I'm making a calculator like the basic calculator on iOS and i need a solution that change the displayed result depending on how many characters are after the dot (not exceeding 9 digits total).

```
Example Table
|result   | wished displayed result | current displayed result
|         |                         |
|1.034    | 1.034                   | 1.03
|1.000567 | 1.000567                | 1.00
|1.2      | 1.2                     | 1.20
```

Using this code:

`result.text = String(format: "%.2f", displayNumber)`

if i get 1.000334 as a result it only show 1.00

**EDIT:**

I forgot to say that i need to not exceed the maximum of 9 characters including the point. If i remove `%.2f` i do not get the desired result because if i get 1.323429249430003442 as a result the displayed result will be 1.323429249430003442 with many numbers (must not exceed 9 digits including the point), otherwise adding `%.9f` is not good because if i get 1.32 as a result the displayed result will be 1.32000000 with a lot of unnecessary zeros.

Thank you all in advance

**EDIT 2 (SOLVED):**

if someone would serve in the future, I solved it this way:

```
var decimalNumberAsString = "\(resultNumber - floor(resultNumber))"
var decimalTrim: NSArray = decimalNumberAsString.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
numberOfDecimalPlaces = decimalTrim.objectAtIndex(1).length
if numberOfDecimalPlaces < 8 {
  numberOfDecimalPlaces = decimalTrim.objectAtIndex(1).length + 1
}
else {
  numberOfDecimalPlaces = 7
}
result.text = String(format: "%.\(numberOfDecimalPlaces)G", resultNumber)
```

Comment: See: [Format placeholders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using `%.2f`. Remove all float formatting. It should solve your issue.

**EDIT** *In response to a comment...*

Or, if you are concerned about long lengths, format to whatever the precision you want. Suppose you want a precision degree of 8, say `%.8f`.

Comment: Right, I forgot to say that i need to not exceed the maximum of 9 characters including the point, excluding %.2f I do not get the desired result

Comment: ..adding %.9f i do not get what I want because if i get 1.32 as a result the displayed result will be 1.32000000 with a lot of unnecessary zeros

Answer (score 0):

I omitted display limitation like this:
import Foundation

```
extension String {
    func numberLongAsDisplay() -> String {
        let digitsToDisplay = 9
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        let number = NSNumber.init( value: Double(self)!)
        let digitsBeforeDot = (self.components(separatedBy: ".").first)!.count
       // let digitsAfterDot = (self.components(separatedBy: ".").last)!.count
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 0
        if digitsBeforeDot >= digitsToDisplay {
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        } else {
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = digitsToDisplay - digitsBeforeDot
        }

        return String(formatter.string(from: number) ?? "")
    }
}
```

example of using:  `print ("88881.0567800111112234".numberLongAsDisplay())`

```
\\result: 88881.0568
```

also unnecessary zeros from the end are removed.